# Mongoose dynamic query building with multiple condition and passing the where clause value as variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to build a mongoose query with multiple where condition. The scenario is User may choose different where clause like search by age, search by email, search user id, etc.. so the where clause changes dynamically.

Also when I pass the value in a variable the data is not getting fetched. If I pass the value directly it works.

Any suggestion or help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: not yet, working on the ui part, once done will try both the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below if your collection fieldname and fieldvalue will be dynamic

```
 let searchdata={};

 //this is for example
 let fieldName = "name";
 let fieldValue = "hello"
 
 searchdata[data.fieldName]={ $regex : data.fieldValue || '', $options : 'i'};
 
 
 User.aggregate([{$match:searchdata}],function(err,data){
      
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Anku, I tried this without regex, but it is not retrieving the data. Probably it has to do with the data type. Does Regex solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

1. Accept the inputs from a user and store them in a variable.

```js
let age = 'whateverUserSpecifiesAge';
let email = 'whateverUserSpecifiesEmail';
let userId = 'whateverUserSpecifiesUserId';
```

> Note: It is not necessary that all of them should have a value some of them can be undefined, That is what dynamic query is all about

2. Construct a where condition that we will use to find the user.

```js
let whereCondition = []

if (age) {
  whereCondition.push({
    'age': age
  })
}

if (email) {
  whereCondition.push({
    'email': email
  })
}

if (userId) {
  whereCondition.push({
    'userId': userId
  })
}
```

3. Now that we have constructed the where condition we can find the user

```js
User.find().or(whereCondition)
  .then(users => { /*logic here*/ })
  .catch(error => { /*error logic here*/ })
```

**Hope this helps**

Comment: Thanks Hadi. The problem with is approach, I am going to display all the fields in the drop down so it is difficult to add each field to an if condition.

Comment: This code is not for the front end or dropdown its for the backend. You can have a dropdown with the age, email, userId, etc, and if the user selects one or more than one just pass the same selected options to the backend(above-given code). and it will work fine.

Comment: My table has nearly 50 fields and not the same field will come up when I select another table. Basically, I am giving a view to the Mongo DB tables with read only access.

Comment: I am not getting what you want to say can you please rephrase!! Thanks

Comment: I am trying to create a nosqlbooster or mongo compass type of application for my company.

Comment: The code I have posted above is to handle data at the backend

Comment: I got that. My problem is how would you handle a collection with 50 columns and user can choose any column to filter the value and I have 20 such tables. I was looking for generic type of filter.